# UITableView custom cell showing weird results?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

UITableView custom cell showing weird results?  I have my code below. Everything was showing fine until I put enough data to go off the initial screen then it started going crazy? My custom cell is shown below.

[image]

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customCell"; // This is identifier given in IB jason set this.

    PostTableCustomCellController *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSLog(@"Cell created");

        NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PostTableCustomCellController" owner:nil options:nil];

        for(id currentObject in nibObjects)
        {
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[PostTableCustomCellController class]])
            {
                cell = (PostTableCustomCellController *)currentObject;  
            }
        }
    }

    Post *post = [postsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.authorName.text = post.author;
    cell.deadline.text = post.deadline;
    cell.description.text = post.description;


    Post *myPost = [postsArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSString *text = myPost.description;

    // Configure the cell...            
    // [[cell authorName] setText:@"1 day"];
    // [[cell distance] setText:@"Austin, TX"];
    // [[cell description] setText:@"dd" ];


    // Might can remove these
    UILabel *locationLabel = (UILabel *) [cell distance];
    UILabel *postTextView = (UILabel *) [cell description];



    //CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(254,88.0f);



    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 88.0f);

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 35.0f);

    CGFloat realHeight = height + 36.0f - (10); 


    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [text sizeWithFont:postTextView.font 
                                constrainedToSize:constraint 
                                    lineBreakMode:postTextView.lineBreakMode];  
    CGRect newFrame = postTextView.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
    postTextView.frame = newFrame;

    [[cell description] sizeToFit];

    CGRect locationRect = locationLabel.frame; // calls the getter
    locationRect.origin.y = realHeight;

    /* CGFloat locRectHeight = postTextView.bounds.size.height; */
    /* locationRect.origin.y = cell.bounds.size.height; */
    locationLabel.frame = locationRect;

    //[[cell authorName] setText:@"jgervin"];
    [[cell viewForBackground] sizeToFit];


    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    Post *myPost = [postsArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSString *text = myPost.description;

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 88.0f);

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 35.0f);

    return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2) + 36.0f; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You queing up old cells as they go off screen do to your `dequeReusableCell`, and the content and properties from the old cell must still be there. When you add content to a cell make sure to clear any previous properties so you can avoid these issues, or just turn off `dequeReusableCell`.

Comment: Noob: how do I shut off deque?

Comment: Ok shut it off and it shows fine now, but now I lose benefits of reuse?

Comment: Can I nil out contentView to do this at once or do I need to clear out each property manually?

Comment: don't shut off dequeue... performance impact can get huge.  Make sure to implement prepareForReuse in your custom cell to clear it.

Comment: how do I implement prepareForReuse?

Comment: how do I implement prepareForReuse?  
Like this? [cell dequeuprepareForReuse ]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a cell-reuse problem.  Why dont your turn off the dequeue-cell mechanism and see if the problem goes away.  If it does, take a look at the code in your custom cell - are you creating multiple copies of the field labels?  It looks that way.